# Pit report mutation coverage Issue when trying to run coverage

Tags: maven, junit, mutation, pitest

[image]

I am getting this error when trying to run mutation coverage 
`mvn org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage` or `mvn verify -PPIT -X` in debug mode.

```
Error:
Execution pit-report of goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.13.0:mutationCoverage failed: Coverage generation minion exited abnormally! (UNKNOWN_ERROR)
```

Looked at bunch of other similar issues or blogs but nothing seems to fixing this error.

I have a lot of stuff added and taken out in `pom.xml` in hopes of something working.

I'm going to add snippets of pom related to this question.

`pom.xml`:

```xml
<project>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit.version>4.9</junit.version>
        <pitest.version>1.4.3</pitest.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
            <artifactId>pitest-junit5-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
                <version>${pitest.version}</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pit-report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>mutationCoverage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <!-- https://github.com/hcoles/pitest/issues/284 -->
                <!-- Need this to support JUnit 5 -->
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pitest-junit5-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.8</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <targetClasses>
                        <param>com.mkyong.examples.*</param>
                    </targetClasses>
                    <targetTests>
                        <param>com.mkyong.examples.*</param>
                    </targetTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
                <version>1.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetClasses>
                        <param>com.your.package.root.want.to.mutate*</param>
                    </targetClasses>
                    <targetTests>
                        <param>com.your.package.root*</param>
                    </targetTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: First upgrade pitest-maven to most recent version 1.13.0 also define the pitest-junit5-plugin (most recent version as well 1.1.2) in the configuration for the pitest-maven ... also you have defined the pitest-maven two times in your pom file(just do once)...furthermore use the most recent version of maven-surefire-plugin(3.0.0) als more important if you like to use spring-boot 3.X you have to use at least JDK17... and upgrade your version of junit-jupiter... to most recent version and if you really need to use junit you should use the most recent version as well...

Comment: If you need to run JUnit 4 based tests you have to add junit-vintage-engine...

Comment: Defining plugins as dependencies is simply wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I have made some example setup which uses spring-boot version 3.0.6. It is also neccessary to define the plugins correctly as shown here... furthermore the dependencies you need..

As I mentioned if you really need to use JUnit 4 you have to add the junit jupiter-vintage engine as a dependency ..

https://central.sonatype.com/search?q=pitest-maven

[For Spring Boot 3.X you have to use JDK17+...](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started.system-requirements)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>xyz.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <spring.boot.version>3.0.6</spring.boot.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
            <arg>-Xlint:-processing</arg>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.10</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1.2184</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
        <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.1</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
            <artifactId>pitest-junit5-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>mutationCoverage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <targetClasses>
                <param>com.your.package.root.want.to.mutate*</param>
              </targetClasses>
              <targetTests>
                <param>com.your.package.root*</param>
              </targetTests>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried a few combinations from what you said and got it to work